# Correct way to do multiprocessing with global variable in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm working on large dataset, to make my function work I have to divide the dataset and do calculation by batch. Here is my code:

```
batch_size = 128
results = []

for i in range(0, len(queries), batch_size):
  
  result = linear_kernel(query[i:i+batch_size], dataset)
  results.append(result)
```

It takes about 5 hours to finish the running.

Now I want to do with multiprocessing. So I define a job function:

query and dataset is a sparse matrix of TFIDF vectorizer

```
def job(i):
  
  return linear_kernel(query[i: i+batch_size], dataset)


with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(job, tqdm(range(0, len(query), batch_size)))
```

Then the problem is:

- I don't know what the results in the executor, I guess the batches must be shuffled. As then I need to process the results, so I need the row index of results must be matched with the row index of `query` data. How can I do it? as I don't know how to modified the output, to make it keep the information row index i.
- Secondly, is it okay to use two variables outside the scope of the function job which are `query` and `dataset`. I don't know much about multiprocessing, if it runs on different cpu then does it copy the data to run on each processor?

Comment: First, tag your question with the platform your are running under (e.g. **windows**). Second, What do `queries` and `dataset` look like. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I mean the python script should be able to run under any platform. queries and dataset are sparse matrix

Comment: First, I believe `len(queries)` should be `len(query)`. Did you make a spell error, or they are two different variables? Second, doe query and/or dataset change during the course of the calculations? It would be easier if they do not change.

Comment: Hi, Yup that's my spell mistake.  For the second concern, no they do not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need function `job`. Your "job" function is `linear_kernel`. Here is my code:

```py
import logging
import random
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(levelname)-8s | %(processName)-14s | %(funcName)-14s | %(message)s",
)


def linear_kernel(query: list, left: int, right: int, dataset):
    logging.debug("Processing batch [%d:%d]", left, right)

    # Fake calculation, which takes a long time to complete
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
    result = left + right

    logging.debug("Return %r", result)
    return result


def main():
    # Fake data
    query = list(range(20))
    dataset = None

    batch_size = 6
    futures = []

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for left_index in range(0, len(query), batch_size):
            # do not pass into the function query[i:i+batch_size]
            # because that is a slice notation, which creates a
            # new array in memory. Instead, pass in the array `query`
            # the left and right indices
            futures.append(
                executor.submit(
                    linear_kernel,
                    query=query,
                    left=left_index,
                    right=left_index + batch_size,
                    dataset=dataset,
                )
            )

    results = [future.result() for future in futures]
    logging.debug("results=%r", results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Sample Output:

```
DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-1 | linear_kernel  | Processing batch [0:6]
DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-3 | linear_kernel  | Processing batch [6:12]
DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-2 | linear_kernel  | Processing batch [12:18]
DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-4 | linear_kernel  | Processing batch [18:24]
DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-4 | linear_kernel  | Return 42
DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-1 | linear_kernel  | Return 6
DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-3 | linear_kernel  | Return 18
DEBUG    | SpawnProcess-2 | linear_kernel  | Return 30
DEBUG    | MainProcess    | main           | results=[6, 18, 30, 42]
```

Notes

- I would like to stress that you should not create a slice such as `query[i:i+batch_size]` and pass that to the function `linear_kernel()`. The slice is really a separate list in memory. Given a large `query` and large `batch_size` we might have a huge memory footprint. Therefore, it is better to pass in the `query`, along with the indices and not creating those slices.
- As you can see from the output, although some calculations are finished out of order, we still have the results in order. That is because the list `futures` keeps track of the order for us
- Of course, I don't know what your data looks like, much less how your calculations work, so I have to fake all of them

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for spending your time on my question. For the first bullet, I have to slice as it cannot compute as a whole due to too big :( . Secondly, I want they share queries and dataset across the processor so it doesn't need to copy the data to each processor to process (that's is what I think how it works)

Comment: For the order of result, I guess I just need return back the index i

Comment: But in your code, it copies the query and dataset to each processor right?

Comment: No my code do not copy `query` or `dataset`. I only passed it into the function `linear_kernel`. If you know C or C++, it is passed by reference, no copy made.